# Angular.js equivalent of `rails generate scaffold`?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, yeoman

I'm writing an app with an angularjs front-end and a Rails backend. One feature of the app allows standard manipulations of a list of employees. Employees can be added and deleted, listed, and their names can be edited.

In a traditional Rails app, most of the code needed to implement these feature can be created using a generator, e.g. with `rails generate scaffold employee name:string`.

Assuming I've created a restful api using the Rails generator command above, is there an equivalent tool I can use to scaffold out a front end in Angular? I suppose I'd want it to generate views, a controller and a service that fetches employee data. I'm aware of the Yeoman angular generator. Can Yeoman do what I need? If so, how?

I'm comfortable with Rails but new with Angular. Does a tool exist to generate basic front end code for a restful resource?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: This would be a very useful feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeoman can do this mostly:

```
yo angular; //generate an angular app
yo angular:route employee; //generates a controller and a view for employee
yo angular:service employee; //generate an employee service
```

then you modify the service employee so it returns a resource (make sure you include angular-resource.js)

```
angular.module('myMod').service('employee', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
   return $resource('/path/to/rest/endpoint/for/employee');
}]);

angular.controller('employee', ['$scope', 'employee', function($scope, employee) {
    $scope.employee = employee.get({id: 1}); 
    //employee is now whatever /path/to/rest/endpoint/for/employee?id=1 returns
}]);
```

Then you can do

```
  employee.name = 'John Smith';
  employee.$save(); 
 //sends a post with {id:1, name:'John Smith'}
```